# Are these courgettes overcooked, if so how can I avoid it?

Tags: overcooking

I set the double oven(I think) to 150 and left thinly sliced courgettes in there for about 20 minutes.

The skin of the courgette looked a bit dark to me and it tasted a bit dry:

[image]

How can one know if it is overcooked and how can I avoid this?

Comment: "Overcooked" is subjective. If you don't like the way your courgettes turned out, you can certainly try cooking them for less time and seeing if you like them better.

Comment: Did you add any oil? or put them in dry?

Comment: I personally don't find that thinly cut summer squash holds up well to cooking.  I either cut about 8-10mm thick slabs and oil then grill it, or cut bite-sized half-moons or quarter moons and sauté it.

Comment: quick question , 150F or C?

Comment: @Austin759 i don’t know as it wasn’t it’s was in a hostel and the c or f is not marked.

Comment: @LightBender I put them in dry.  But I’ve done it previously on another cooker it came out fine even though I put them in dry.

Comment: @Austin759 with some browning visible it would have to be C (unless that one localised spot is damage rather than browned by the cooking)

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest issue is you're baking them instead of roasting them. In order to roast them, you'll need a much higher temperature. 230c or 450f is about right. As Joe pointed out, the pieces are a bit thin for roasting. Spears or large chunks will serve you better. Roast them skin side down and brushing on a little olive oil will prevent the skins from drying out.

Answer (score 0):

As in everything, you should keep an eye on what you are cooking; cooking is not an exact science.

Following timing instructions when baking/roasting is sometime problematic because each oven is slightly different and each ingredient will be slightly different from region to region (and season to season...).

So to answer the question, it depends.

If you feel they are overcooked, just cook them less next time or change the oven temperature or change recipe or cooking method.